# ios xcode9.0 swift4.0 MQTT - How to use certificate to connect to MQTT server?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, certificate, mqtt

This is the task that I would like to do in the iphone app:

1. download & install a certificate "mosquitto.org.crt" from test.mosquitto.org
2. connect to the mqtt server "test.mosquitto.org" at 8883 port
3. expected to see "connect success" in debug message
4. exit the app, delete the certificate in iphone
5. go back the app & retry connect to the mqtt server at 8883 port again
6. expected to see: connection failed

I tried CocoaMQTT:
https://github.com/emqtt/CocoaMQTT
but CocoaMQTT could still connect to the server successfully even if the certificate has been deleted.

Here is the code that I modified from the cocoaMQTT example:

```
import UIKit
import CocoaMQTT

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var mqtt: CocoaMQTT?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mqttSetting()
    }



    func mqttSetting() {
        let clientID: String = "testID123456789"
        let mqttServer: String = "test.mosquitto.org"
        let mqttPort: UInt16 = 8883
        let useSSL: Bool = true

        mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: mqttServer, port: mqttPort)
        mqtt!.username = nil
        mqtt!.password = nil
        mqtt!.keepAlive = 60
        mqtt!.delegate = self

        if useSSL == true{
            mqtt!.enableSSL = true
            mqtt!.allowUntrustCACertificate = true
        }

        mqtt!.connect()
    }

}

extension ViewController: CocoaMQTTDelegate {
    // Optional ssl CocoaMQTTDelegate
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        TRACE("trust: \(trust)")
        /// Validate the server certificate
        ///
        /// Some custom validation...
        ///
        /// if validatePassed {
        ///     completionHandler(true)
        /// } else {
        ///     completionHandler(false)
        /// }
        completionHandler(true)
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
        TRACE("ack: \(ack)")

        if ack == .accept {
            mqtt.subscribe("chat/room/animals/client/+", qos: CocoaMQTTQOS.qos1)


        }
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didStateChangeTo state: CocoaMQTTConnState) {
        TRACE("new state: \(state)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        TRACE("message: \(String(describing: message.string?.description)), id: \(id)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
        TRACE("id: \(id)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16 ) {
        TRACE("message: \(String(describing: message.string?.description)), id: \(id)")

    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopic topic: String) {
        TRACE("topic: \(topic)")
    }

    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopic topic: String) {
        TRACE("topic: \(topic)")
    }

    func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        TRACE()
    }

    func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        TRACE()
    }

    func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: Error?) {
        TRACE("\(err.debugDescription)")
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func TRACE(_ message: String = "", fun: String = #function) {
        let names = fun.components(separatedBy: ":")
        var prettyName: String
        if names.count == 1 {
            prettyName = names[0]
        } else {
            prettyName = names[1]
        }

        if fun == "mqttDidDisconnect(_:withError:)" {
            prettyName = "didDisconect"
        }

        print("[TRACE] [\(prettyName)]: \(message)")
    }
}
```

The above code give the following result in the debug window (I have  already deleted the certificate of test.mosquitto.org in my iPhone):

```
[TRACE] [didStateChangeTo]: new state: connecting
[TRACE] [didReceive]: trust: <SecTrustRef: 0x170129420>
[TRACE] [didStateChangeTo]: new state: connected
[TRACE] [didConnectAck]: ack: accept
[TRACE] [didSubscribeTopic]: topic: chat/room/animals/client/+
[TRACE] [mqttDidPing]: 
[TRACE] [mqttDidReceivePong]: 
[TRACE] [mqttDidPing]: 
[TRACE] [mqttDidReceivePong]:
```

I expected that the connection to mqtt server should not be successful because I have deleted the certificate in iPhone. However, the connection still successful, which is not my expected result. Any idea how to do?

Comment: This is far too broad, pick one of the libraries you mentioned and edit the question to include the code you tried and the errors you got and then somebody will help you fix it.

Comment: Hi hardillb! Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question and focus on using CocoaMQTT. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your server may using one-way certification.

You can use one-way certification:

```
mqtt!.enableSSL = true
```

No certificate is required locally.

If you want to trust all untrust CA certificates, you can do this:

```
mqtt.allowUntrustCACert = true
```

(p12 is for 2-way certification)